# Out of memory using Keras on GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras

I would like to apply Deep Learning to my classification problem where the size of the gray-scale images in my dataset are `200x200`. Currently, I am testing DL on a very small  subset (152 images) of my large datasets (over 15,000 images); and I am using Keras (version '1.1.2') library with Theano (version '0.9.0.dev4') backend in Python (Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)). My code runs in CPU, but it is very slow. So, I switched to GPU. However, I am getting below error:

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTS 450 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 70.0% of memory, cuDNN not available)

Train on 121 samples, validate on 31 samples
Epoch 1/200
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-247bada3ec1a>", line 2, in <module>
    verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 652, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1111, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 826, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 811, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 886, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)

  File "/home/user1/anaconda2/envs/keras_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 873, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\

MemoryError: Error allocating 160579584 bytes of device memory (CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY).
Apply node that caused the error: GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + Abs(i1)))},no_inplace}(CudaNdarrayConstant{[[[[ 0.5]]]]}, GpuElemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0)
Toposort index: 60
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, True, True, True)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 1, 1, 1), (32, 32, 198, 198)]
Inputs strides: [(0, 0, 0, 0), (1254528, 39204, 198, 1)]
Inputs values: [CudaNdarray([[[[ 0.5]]]]), 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuContiguous(GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + Abs(i1)))},no_inplace}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I tried the suggested solutions (`optimizer=fast_compile` and `optimizer=None`) but it didn't work out. I know the problem is related to the image sizes, because it worked when I resized the images to `50x50`.

Do you know how I can fix the problem to be able to apply it to `200x200` images?

I am using Linux Mageia 5 and my GPU information is:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] (rev a1)
[    64.299] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    64.313] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    64.439] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
```

I am not sure if using cuDNN is a correct solution to my problem, but I have already tried using it by including `optimizer_including=cudnn` in `.theanorc`; but I am getting below error:

```
AssertionError: cuDNN optimization was enabled, but Theano was not able to use it. We got this error: 
Device not supported
```

I think it might be because my GPU compute compatibility is 2.1 (which is less than the cudnn GPU cc requirement (3.0 or higher)).

I would be thankful if you could help me to fix the issue and run DL on my large datasets?

Comment: It's difficult to say without looking at the code but could you load the images in smaller batches to the gpu?

Comment: cuDNN won't work with your GTS450 Fermi (GF106) GPU.  cuDNN requires kepler GPUs.  It seems you are out of memory on your GPU, and the GTS450 is a pretty old, low end GPU without much memory (1GB).

Comment: @Atirag I tried a smaller batch size, but I am getting a similar error.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Is using cuDNN the only solution to fix this kind of problems?

Comment: @SaraG. In that case you probably would need to use something that allows for more customization on how to handle the data. Maybe try tensorflow or theano? Or just run the code on a machine with a better GPU. I'm not so familiar with keras so I don't know if you can customize it in a way that it loads the data in a smarter way.

Comment: No, I don't think cuDNN is the only solution.  I suspect that if you had a GPU with more memory, you might not run into the issue.  There might be other ways to work around it as well, as discussed by others here.

Answer (score -1):

it says that you GPU is out of memory. So change the batch size and don't load all the data to the GPU directly using the shared variable but iterate between them. Otherwise find another GPU with higher memory capacity

Comment: I changed the batch size to a smaller value but it didn't resolve the issue. Could you please elaborate your second suggested solution (using shared variable and iterating between them) a little bit more? Do you mean that I need to divide my input images into different subsets and using shared variables feed them to CNN in different iterations in each epoch?

Comment: when you put your images in the shared variable just add the amount of the patch size not the full dataset. and in each iteration load again the new images and update the shared variable. what I'm saying here reduce the amount of data loaded on your GPU

Comment: Such an unhelpful answer. Obviously the problem is that too much data is being loaded into the GPU. You give no insight on how to actually adjust the amount of data loaded, and merely reiterate "reduce the amount of data".

Comment: @Feras great answer, it helped me out